# Probability of being in a group within a team

Tags: probability

It's been a while since I've been in school, so my math is really rusty.
There's a game I've been playing where there's a group of ten players, and two are randomly selected as "imposters".
What's the probability that I will be chosen as one of the imposters?

I reasoned it as:
Number of ways for me to be an imposter = $\binom{1}1$.
Number of ways for the second person to be chosen as an imposter = $\binom{9}1$.
Total sample space = $\binom{10}2\binom{8}8$.

So the probability that I am an imposter is $$\frac{\binom{1}1\binom{9}1}{\binom{10}2\binom{8}8}= \frac{9}{45}$$

When I looked at $m$ imposters and $n$ players, I used the same logic to get a final probability of $\frac{m}{n}$. For some reason I wasn't expecting this result (that it would simply be a flat ratio). Is there some intuition to this? I expected the result to be less than $m/n$, since there seems to be so many permutations to pick a team of $m$ imposters, (for example, if $m = 10$, $n = 140$)

Comment: Your work is now correct.  In the general case, the probability that you will be selected as one of the $m$ imposters is $$\frac{\binom{1}{1}\binom{n - 1}{m - 1}}{\binom{n}{m}} = \frac{m}{n}$$ which makes sense since there are $m$ ways you could be one of the imposters and $n$ people from which to choose the imposters.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is incorrect: You are looking for ways in which you are one of the imposters. There are 9 possibilities, namely you and someone else, where someone else is chosen among 9 people. Note that the order of you and the other person is not important, so it suffices to choose the other person.

Edit: In general, you have $n$ people (including you) and $m$ imposters.

The probability that you are an imposter is: $\frac{n-1\choose {m-1}}{n\choose m}=\frac{m}{n}$. The numerator is again the number of imposters except you, and the denominator is again the choice of imposters without any further constraints involved.

This, in my opinion is actually very intuitive - m out of n people are imposters, so you have $m/n$ probability of being an imposter. This is something like "1 out of 300 people have Coronavirus, so the probability of you having it (from a very objective point of view - I don't know you at all) is 1/300.

Comment: Thanks, corrected! English is not my first language...

Comment: I wish I knew a second language as well as you know English.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected it to $\binom{9}1$, it still simplified to 0.2

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen the rest of the question, now I have updated it!